# Compilation error while calling method with generic types

Tags: java, oop, generics, jdbc

This will be very stupid question, but I am not able to understand why I am getting compilation error while using the below code. I have a method like

```
public <T> List<T> mapGenericEntity(ResultSet resultSet, Class<T> type) throws SQLException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IntrospectionException, InvocationTargetException {
     List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();
     while(resultSet.next()) {
        T instance = type.newInstance();
        for(Field field: type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(excludeFields.indexOf(field.getName()) != -1) {
                continue;
            }
            Object value = resultSet.getObject(field.getName());
            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), type);
            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod();
            method.invoke(instance, value);
        }
        entities.add(instance);
    }
    return entities;
}
```

and I am calling this method like below

```
mapGenericEntity(resultSet, Product.class);
```

but I am getting compilation error as follows

```
incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to com.company.Product
```

What am I missing here ?

EDIT:

**Solution**

Ok, So I was being stupid. The mapGenericEntity method returns a list of Product objects and I was assigning it to a single instance. I was doing something like

`Product product = mapGenericEntity(resultSet, Product.class);`

but in Intellij there was a red underline below

`mapGenericEntity(resultSet, Product.class);`

and not below

`Product product`

Also the error message should be more understandable.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. When and where exactly is the error happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error (Eclipse Mars 4.5.0)

Comment: When I compile this with mvn clean package command the compilation error is on the line where I am calling the method. I am using java 8

Comment: Still can't reproduce. You'd probably help us with a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure will do that, by the way this error is only occur for a one particular method not in other methods. I will try to debug more.

Comment: @Thiago Porciúncula I updated my question